# c++ qt undefined reference to `_imp

Tags: c++, qt, shared-libraries

I use Qt Creator to make static C++ library and a Qt application for it.

My lib includes MyLib_global.h:

```
#if defined(MYLIB_LIBRARY)
#  define MYLIBSHARED_EXPORT Q_DECL_EXPORT
#else
#  define MYLIBSHARED_EXPORT Q_DECL_IMPORT
#endif
```

myclass.h file:

```
#include "MyLib_global.h"

class MYLIBSHARED_EXPORT MyClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:            
        enum Log
        {
            SomeValue,
            NotARealValue
        };
        MyClass(double var, Log e);
        ~MyClass();
}
```

And myclass.cpp file:

```
#include "myclass.h"

MyClass::MyClass(double var, Log e)
{
}
MyClass::~MyClass()
{
}
```

This block I wrote in .pro file:

```
QT       -= gui
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++0x
TARGET = MyLib
TEMPLATE = lib
CONFIG += staticlib
```

So I build this project using MinGW 4.7 32bit on Windows. Then I tried to include library in Qt GUI app by writing this in .pro file:

```
LIBS += -Ld:/l -lAgemarkerCore
INCLUDEPATH += d:/l/includes
```

*"l" is a folder on my "D:" drive where I placed "libMyLib.a" file. In "d:/l/includes" folder I placed all headers from MyLib project.*

Now I'm trying to create a new instance of MyClass in mainwindow.cpp file:

```
#include "myclass.h"

void MainWindow::someFunction()
{
    double var = 3.5;
    MyClass::Log enum_value = MyClass::SomeValue;
    MyClass* c = new MyClass(var, enum_value);
}
```

And there is a problem. After I compile this GUI project using the same computer placed in the same room running on the same system, the same IDE and the same compiler I used with MyLib, I get this error:

```
mainwindow.cpp:29: error: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN12MyClassC1EPdS0_S0_xiNS_3LogEi'
```

I searched lots of forums and tried few solutions that I've found, but they didn't help. Most of this errors are concerned with GCC compiler, and simply changing the order of project files and libs helped with it, but I use MinGW with only one lib, therefore there isn't any order of libs.

What can I do to link my library successful?

Comment: what line is line 29 in mainwindow.cpp?

Comment: MyClass* c = new MyClass(var, enum_value);

Comment: Are you sure those are the correct preprocessor instructions in MyLib_global.h?  commands that I believe would be correct are something like: 
`#ifndef MYLIBSHARED_EXPORT Q_DECL_EXPORT`
`#define MYLIBSHARED_EXPORT Q_DECL_EXPORT`
`//actual definitions...`
`#endif`

Comment: Oh, thanks! That was tricky, and now all works fine. I don't know exactly why those lines has been written in that way: I didn't change them since I created a project in Qt.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are compiling a *static library* (`config += staticlib`), but you are using the `Q_DECL_EXPORT` and `Q_DECL_IMPORT` macros. These macros are only used *when compiling shared libraries* because they imply DLL linkage (on Windows, at least).

When the app tries to compile against your *static* library, it attempts to link it as if it were a shared library because the headers specify DLL linkage. This breaks, and the result is a linker error.

The solution is to either build a shared library, or leave off the `MYLIBSHARED_EXPORT` (heck, it even says `SHARED` right there in the macro name!)

Comment: It was already defined. Sorry that I hadn't pointed it out in my question, I did think it doesn't matter. The answer is in comments to the question.

Comment: Hang on -- you made a static library? I think that's the reason it didn't work -- you don't need `Q_DECL_EXPORT` or `Q_DECL_IMPORT` in a static library.

Comment: Yes, it is static since I wrote `CONFIG += staticlib` in .pro file.

Comment: Yeah, but you still use the EXPORT/IMPORT macros. That's going to invoke DLL linkage, so the library will attempt to link against `_imp_` which is (IIRC) a DLL-only thing.

Comment: @ahawkthomas: in the interests of clarifying what's going on, I updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I solved all `undefined reference to '__imp_..` errors with adding `QT += gui widgets` in the .pro file of the project. I'm using `Qt Creator 4.12.4`.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar error with GraphicsView today. If you use CMake then just add Qt::Widgets into your CMakeList:

```
# I use Qt6

find_package(Qt6Widgets)
include_directories(${Qt6Widgets_INCLUDE_DIRS})

...some your code...

target_link_libraries(
    <Your_Library> PRIVATE
    Qt6::Widgets
)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).